# SpringBoot3 SpringWeb and GraphQL throws No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-graphql

I am upgrading to SpringBoot3 (3.1.2). My app is a MVC with spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-graphql on the path (Maven). When I call GraphQL (GraphiQL or Postman), I get an exception saying No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context. I've been staring at it a while and not sure where to go with this. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ContextAccessor for contextType: class reactor.util.context.Context0 at io.micrometer.context.ContextRegistry.getContextAccessorForWrite(ContextRegistry.java:220) at io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshot.updateContextInternal(DefaultContextSnapshot.java:63) at io.micrometer.context.DefaultContextSnapshot.updateContext(DefaultContextSnapshot.java:43) at reactor.core.publisher.MonoContextWrite.subscribeOrReturn(MonoContextWrite.java:38) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4475) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4605) at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.toFuture(Mono.java:5010) at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$ReactorRegistrar.lambda$registerAdapters$5(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:244) at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapter.fromPublisher(ReactiveAdapter.java:121) at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.DefaultAsyncServerResponse.create(DefaultAsyncServerResponse.java:186) at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse.async(ServerResponse.java:250) at org.springframework.graphql.server.webmvc.GraphQlHttpHandler.handleRequest(GraphQlHttpHandler.java:111) at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:107) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
```

Comment: Not enough information. What is your pom file? What is your code? Create a minimal verifiable example to reproduce the error and post it here, please. Don't put here the whole code, only extract a minimal example which still produces the error.

Comment: At the first glance it looks like your project is missing the reactor dependency. But let's see after you put here the minimum example.

Comment: how did you resolve this issue? we are also facing the similar issue,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Arg...sorry for the preemptive post. I had reactor core 3.4.28 on my classpath. SpringBoot3 includes 3.5.8 in the reactor BOM. So, there's an incompatibility effecting the ContextRegistry for GraphQL.